# Replacing CSS file using JavaScript works only halfway

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to replace a CSS file with another one on a page by toggling between the day/night themes using an eventlistener. I tried to do this in numerous ways, but none of them worked completely.

My default theme is dark and I can only manage to change it to light theme using my code, not back to dark again. What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot everyone!

```
colorModeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (cssFile.href = "styles.css") {
      cssFile.setAttribute("href", "styles-daylight.css") 
  } else {
    cssFile.setAttribute("href", "styles.css")
  }
})
```

```
colorModeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (cssFileDay.disabled = true) {
    cssFileDay.disabled = false
    cssFile.disabled = true
  } else {
    cssFileDay.disabled = true
    cssFile.disabled = false
  }
})
```

```
colorModeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const cssLink = document.createElement("link")
  if (cssFile.href = "styles.css") {
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"
    cssLink.href = "styles-daylight.css"
    document.head.appendChild(cssLink)
    cssFile.disabled = true
  } else if (document.head.cssLink) {
    document.head.removeChild(cssLink)
    cssFile.disabled = false
  }
})
```

```
colorModeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const cssLink = document.createElement("link")
  if (cssFile.href = "styles.css") {
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"
    cssLink.href = "styles-daylight.css"
    document.head.appendChild(cssLink)
    cssFile.disabled = true
  } else if (document.head.cssLink) {
    var linkNode = document.querySelector('link[href*="styles-daylight.css"]')
    linkNode.removeChild(linkNode)
    cssFile.disabled = false
  }
})
```

Comment: Tracking/swapping CSS hrefs and the `disabled` property seems like a lot of work. Why not just add/remove a single class name to your `<body>` and style your CSS so it recognizes the presence/absence of that body class and uses the appropriate light/dark theme?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operators-and-what-is-si

Comment: Yes, it does answer my question, thanks a lot. However, I did not manage to understand what you meant by 'Why not just add/remove a single class name to your <body> and style your CSS so it recognizes the presence/absence of that body class and uses the appropriate light/dark theme?'. Can you elaborate if it's not too difficult? Thanks a lot!

Comment: See my answer that I just posted. Also see [Add button to switch between light and dark mode using two prefers-color-scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73693983/add-button-to-switch-between-light-and-dark-mode-using-two-prefers-color-scheme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold on. Yes you found the error. But ALL four of the sample code you showed on  your question have `if` statements like

```
if (x = true)
```

The single `=` is an attribution command that, in JavaScript (and other C derived languages), return a value so the `if` statement will always be true.

The comparison, which is what you want is a double equal (`==`).

The triple equal (`===`) is also a comparison but it compares the data type between the left and right sides as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer and it's a small thing, as usual in this cases. However, I don't understand why it didn't work the way I posted it above.

That was I was using.

```
colorModeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (cssFileDay.disabled = true) {
    cssFileDay.disabled = false
    cssFile.disabled = true
  } else {
    cssFileDay.disabled = true
    cssFile.disabled = false
  }
})
```

And I had to change (cssFileDay.disabled = true) either to (cssFileDay.disabled === true) or (cssFileDay.disabled). And it started working well.

Comment: `if (cssFileDay.disabled = true)` You're __*setting*__ disabled to true here, not checking if it's true.

Comment: Technically, it's first setting it to true, and *then* checking if it's true...which it will always be.

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify your code by toggling a class name that indicates light/dark mode:

```js
document.getElementById('colorModeBtn').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('daylight')
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: darkblue; /* default (dark mode) */
}

body.daylight {
  background-color: yellow; /* daylight mode */
}

/* Add other CSS here */
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="colorModeBtn">
    Switch mode
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Never thought of doing it like this, it's much easier.